# bad libjpeg scaling quality when loading images

Tags: resize, scale, libjpeg

libjpeg-9a can be used to load images already scaled down. The comments in jidctint.c sounded promising:

- This can be seen as direct low-pass downsampling from the DCT domain
- point of view rather than the usual spatial domain point of view,
- yielding significant computational savings and results at least
- as good as common bilinear (averaging) spatial downsampling.

So I compared scaling the image using djpeg to scaling the image using Photoshops bilinear scaling algorithm. What I found out was surprising:
1) The bilinear resize quality of Photoshop was significantly better than that of djpeg.
2) Moreover I resized files with different quality settings (dithering, upsampling) and received binary identical files.

For further details I've prepared a reproduction set: http://light-in-a-box.net/libjpeg-reproduction.zip

It includes the original image used for my tests, as well as batch files which produce the libjpeg-output using djpeg. For convenience I’ve also included the resized images (especially those of Photoshop) and a notes.txt file which exactly describes the circumstances of the tests.

Any help on that is really appreciated.